# Modifying function

Tags: r

I have a dataset that includes multiple patient records from different patients. I also have a function that I am writing where I want it to go through each unique patient and check to see if at time point 1, treatment 1 equals treatment 2. It is running however its only giving me results for the patients who have only one record. I was hoping to keep it as a loop inside the function because I still have more checks I need to add once I get passed this. So if anyone can help me modify the loop to see why it's not giving me results for every patient, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Patient = c('Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', "Angel", "Angel", "Angel", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Cara"),
  V1 = c(1, 150, 375, 1, 150, 375, 1, 150, 375, 1),
  V2 = c(150, 375,568,150, 375, 568, 150, 375, 568, 375),
  R1 = c("Disease","Response","Response", "Disease","Disease", "Response","Disease", "Response", "Response", "Disease"),
  R2 = c("Response", "Response", "Death", "Disease", "Response", "Death", "Response", "Response", "Response", "Disease"),
  T1 = c("A","A", "B", "A","B","B", "A","A","C", "A"),
  T2 = c("A", "B","B",  "B","B","B", "A","C","C" , "A"))
```

```
Time <- function(id) {
  subset_df <- df[df$Patient == id, ]
  start <- NULL 
  end <- NULL
  for (i in 1:nrow(subset_df)) { 
    if (subset_df$V1[i] == 1 && subset_df$T1[i] == subset_df$T2[i]) { 
      start <- subset_df$V2[i] 
    }  else { 
      start <- "Never Responded"
    }
  }
  return(start)
}

ids <- unique(df$Patient)
times <- lapply(ids, Time)
```

In my function I have written that if at visit 1 (V1) treatment 1 (T1) equals treatment 2 (T2) then I want it to record the corresponding visit 2 (V2) number which is in days. And if the two treatments are not equal at visit 1 (else) then write never responded. So when I run this function it only returns with Cara V2 when it should also return Dave and Joe and say Never Responded for Angel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making a classic beginner looping mistake - inside your loop you redefine `start` every time without "remembering" the last iteration. When `i = 1`, you might set `start <- 150`. But then when `i = 2` you do `start <- "Never Responded"` and the old `start <- 150` is gone forever.

The bad solution is to concatenate each time, making `start` "grow": `start <- c(start, subset_df$V2[i])`, etc. This is bad because growing objects is terribly slow. Even with a few hundred iterations, this will start to take noticeable time.

The slightly better solution is to initialize `start` to the correct length from the start: instead of `start <- NULL`, do `start <- rep(NA, nrow(subset_df))`. Then you can assign to the correct position, `start[i] <- ...`. This avoids the performance pitfall of growing an object, but it doesn't take advantage of R's vectorization.

The better solution is to skip the loop entirely and vectorize:

```
start <- ifelse(subset_df$V1 == 1 & subset_df$T1 == subset_df$T2, subset_df$V2, NA)
```

(Note that you can't mix numeric class and character class in the same vector, so using `NA` is better than "Never responded" since you are mixing this with numbers.)

Doing that, you can also realize that there's nothing "by group" about this - the whole thing is "by row", so you don't need the `lapply` at all, you can do this all at once on your whole data:

```
start <- ifelse(df$V1 == 1 & df$T1 == df$T2, df$V2, NA)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and solutions! I now understand loop way better